# Define getRowClass function in the controller

Tags: extjs

I'm using getRowClass function for custom grid row styling. In a panel component I have 2 similar grids which should have the same getRowClass logic. I would like to define the function body in the controller binded to the parent component. Below I placed some test code that illustrates the problem. In the example getRowClass is set to point to color function defined in the main controller, however this function cannot be seen in this scope. I don't have much experience in extJS and I don't know how to solve this kind of scope problems, any help will be appreciated.

```
Ext.define('Test.controller', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.main',

 color : function(row,index){
     return 'green-row';
 }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
 win = new Ext.Window({
    title:'Test',
    layout:'fit',
    width:400,
    closeAction:'close',
    target : document.getElementById('buttonId'),
    plain: true,
    controller: 'main',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        store: Ext.create("testApp.store.Objects"),
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',

        columns : [{
            text : 'Column1',
            dataIndex : 'Column1'
        },{
            text : 'Column2',
            dataIndex : 'Column2'
        },{
            text : 'Column3',
            dataIndex : 'Column3'
        }],
        viewConfig : {
            getRowClass : 'color'
        }
    }]
 });
 Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    renderTo: Ext.getElementById('buttonId'),
    text: 'Click Me',
    listeners: {
       click: function() {
          win.show();
       }
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All config objects are only relevant at instantiation time of a class and don't have any effect afterwards.

You can resolve you issue like this:

```
listeners : {
            afterrender: function(p){
               p.getView().getRowClass = this.up('window').getController().color;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification.